# Issue while using composition include in JSF, no autocomplete in IDE

Tags: jsf, primefaces, intellij-idea, composite-component

I'm creating web application. Now I'm trying to aggregate common forms and dialogs in one file and reuse them using `<ui:include`.

```
<ui:include src="create/commonCreateDialog.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="creatingDocument" value="#{control.document}"/>
</ui:include>
```

Here is part of `commonCreateDialog.xhtml`:

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['structure']}"/>
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{creatingDocument.structureNumberIndex}">
    <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel=""/>
    <f:selectItems value="#{data.structuralIndex}"
                   var="index"
                   itemLabel="#{index.label}"
                   itemValue="#{index.value}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

As you can see, I'm using `creatingDocument` in `commonCreateDialog.xhtml`, that was passed as `param` in `<ui:include>`.

Everything works fine, no errors after compilation and while working with this forms. The problem is that my IDE (Intellij IDEA 13) **does not autocomplete** this `createtingDocument`. It does not understand that `creatingDocument` is instance of `control.document` which is my class `Document.java`.

Also IDE displaying with grey color this `creatingDocument`, that means IDE do not know what type is it.

[image]

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is Document.java is a managedbean?

Comment: @wittakarn, yes it is.